# Setting the object size in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I need to set the specific size and position for objects in Illustrator. For example, I need to set the size to 100 × 50 mm, but Illustrator automatically sets its size to 100.189 × 50.094 mm. Same thing happens with position.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to "Align to pixel grid"

Select your object, **Open Your transform window (shift + F8)** and **Uncheck "Align to pixel grid"**

and then enter values it will work perfect now

[image]